# JS Script does not get loaded in wordpress via Hooks

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use hooks for a js script.  The script page does not loads .
**But it loads when I login to wp-admin**

*in themes functions.php*

```
add_action('init', 'test_ajax_load_scripts');

function test_ajax_load_scripts() { 


    // load our jquery file that sends the $.post request
    wp_register_script( "ajax-test", get_template_directory_uri().'/ajax-test.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // make the ajaxurl var available to the above script
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-test', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );  

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-test', get_template_directory_uri() .'/ajax-test.js', array( 'jquery' ));

}
```

*ajax-test.js*

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    alert("in ajax-testjs");

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress uses different hooks for dashboard and frontend.

1.If you want to use scripts or style on front end then see following example-

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

2.If you want to user script or style on admin side then you need to see following example

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

**Note - you should use unique name for style-name or script-name.**

To know more use following link-
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: You need to define different handle name whenever enqueue any script.

Comment: I think you tried same handle name for multiple scripts.